# How to load a image to image control in wpf?

Tags: wpf, image, mvvm

I'm developing an application in wpf with mvvm pattern.

in my application, i need to select a image and show in a form and then save it to database.

in the wpf form, i'm using a image control to display the image.

in my view model, I open the file dialog and assign the Image Property.

```
BitmapImage image;
public BitmapImage Image
{
    get { return image; }
    set
    {
        image = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("Image");
    }
}

...

OpenFileDialog file = new OpenFileDialog();
Nullable<bool> result =file.ShowDialog();

if (File.Exists(file.FileName))
{
    image = new BitmapImage();
    image.BeginInit();
    image.UriSource = new Uri(file.FileName, UriKind.Absolute);
    image.EndInit();
}
```

my xaml part is

```
 <Image Height="144" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Source="{Binding Image}"
        Margin="118,144,0,0" Name="imgData" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="340" />
```

I'm not able to see the image in the form. How?

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF image control source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241156/wpf-image-control-source)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to assign the `Image` property, not the `image` field. Otherwise the PropertyChanged event isn't raised:

```
if (File.Exists(file.FileName))
{
    Image = new BitmapImage(new Uri(file.FileName, UriKind.Absolute));
}
```

---

Please note also that it would make sense to declare the `Image` property to be of type `ImageSource`, which is a base class of `BitmapImage`. That would allow instances of other types derived from `ImageSource` to be assigned to the property, e.g. `BitmapFrame` or `WriteableBitmap`.