# Load Image from URL and bind to Image control in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, image

I have http url, and have to show image from that URL.

How to load it and bind to ImageControl?

Here is my URL:

```
string url = www.abc.com/abc/getDigitalDocument.htm?name=" + name + "&password=" + passwrod + "&flag=Photo";
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!!

Comment: Can you add more code? what have you tried till now?

Comment: @TheUknown no bro, I am new in this scenario. I am Windows Phone Dev. I have just URL and show the picture.

Comment: Alright bro. I think you have your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241156/wpf-image-control-source

Comment: @TheUknown It is WPF, I am using "Web Site Project". Thanks

Comment: Oh oops, sorry.This: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/430320/Previewing-Image-in-ASP-NET-Image-Control-using-Cs

Comment: I have worked in .Net. I'm guessing this is easy. All you  need to do would be your `ImageControlName.ImageUrl = " value"` in code.

Comment: @TheUknown but it is not ".gif" or ".jpg" URL. Its is web url. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Ok, its directly done using "Image.ImaegUrl" :

```
Image1.ImageUrl = "www.abc.com/abc/getDigitalDocument.htm?name=" + name + "&password=" + passwrod + "&flag=Photo";
```